# Trying to write a JavaScript "for loop" in the form of "while loop" while maintaining the same function

Tags: javascript, for-loop, while-loop, console.log

I was trying to convert this "for loop"

```
    for(rows=0;rows<26;rows++ ){
    for(seats=0;seats<100;seats++ ){
        console.log(rows+"-"+seats);
    }
}
```

to a while loop in javaScript and that's what I got

```
rows=0;
seats=0;
while(rows<26){

    while(seats<100){
        console.log(rows+"-"+seats);
        seats++;
    }
    rows++ ;
}
```

but the output wasn't the same and I think there is an issue with the while loop that I don't know .. I hope that anyone can help

Comment: Notice that both versions are missing `var` (or `let`) declarations for the variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reset seats = 0 for each row.

```js
rows=0;
seats=0;
while(rows<26){
    seats = 0;
    while(seats<100){
        console.log(rows+"-"+seats);
        seats++;
    }
    rows++;
}
```

Comment: or move the assignment of seats inside of the first loop.

Comment: @NinaScholz Which would in fact be the only valid conversion that maintains the same functionality as the `for`.